# Logical value interpretation function returning incorrect results

Tags: python, logical-operators

My task is to write a function interpret that takes two arguments, a valid expression and an interpretation, and gives the truth value if the entire expression is true in this particular interpretation. The logical constants and expressions should be managed as strings, so you need to implement their own functions for the Boolean operations.

Note that the function should return "true" or "false" not True or False.

Here are some possible inputs and outputs:

```
>>> interpret(["door_open", "AND", "cat_gone"], 
               {"door_open" : "false", "cat_gone" : "true", "cat_asleep" : "true"} )
'false'        
>>> interpret(["cat_asleep", "OR", ["NOT", "cat_gone"]],
               {"door_open" : "false", "cat_gone" : "true", "cat_asleep" : "true"})
'true'
>>> interpret(["true", "OR", "true"], {})
'true'
>>> interpret("cat_gone", {"door_open": "false", "cat_gone": "true"})
'true'
>>> interpret(["NOT", ["NOT", ["NOT", ["cat_asleep", "OR", ["NOT", "cat_asleep"]]]]],
               {"cat_asleep": "false"})
'false'
>>> interpret(["NOT", "AND", "true"], {"NOT":"true"})
'true'
>>> interpret(["NOT", "AND"], {"AND": "false"})
'true'
```

So this is my code down here, it works for the first and last case shown above but in all others I either get the wrong output or none at all. Whats is the problem here and how do I fix it?

```
def and_operator(statement, values):
    if isinstance(statement[0], str) and isinstance(statement[2], str):
        statement[0] = (statement[0], values)
        statement[2] = (statement[2], values)
        return "true" if statement[0] == "true" and statement[2] == "true" else "false"

    if isinstance(statement[0], str):
        return and_operator()
    return interpret(statement[0], values), interpret(statement[2], values)


def or_operator(statement, values):
    if isinstance(statement[0], str) and isinstance(statement[2], str):
        statement[0] = (statement[0], values)
        statement[2] = (statement[2], values)
        return "true" if statement[0] == "true" or statement[2] == "true" else "false"


def not_operator(expr, value):
    if isinstance(expr[1], str):
        return "false" if expr[1] == "true" else "true"
    return interpret(expr[1:], value)


def real_values(element, interp):
    if element in interp:
        element = interp[element]
        return element


def item_is_list(e, i):
    return True if isinstance(e[i], list) else False


def interpret(statement, interpretation):
    length = len(statement)
    if item_is_list(statement, 0):
        return statement

    if length == 3:
        if statement[1] == "AND":
            return and_operator(statement, interpretation)
        elif statement[1] == "OR":
            return or_operator(statement, interpretation)
    elif len(statement) == 2:
        return not_operator(statement, interpretation)
```

Comment: I get different (also incorrect) results from what you show in your question. Regardless, it's difficult to debug someone else's code when almost no description of what the code does or how it operates internally (other than the buggy code itself) is given. What algorithm is it trying to implement?

Comment: Without knowing any additional details, from reading your code I can tell that two of your functions have a problem of implicitly returning `None` when they execute all the way to their very end (because no previous conditional statements were `True` so no previous `return` statement was encountered and executed).

Comment: Do happen to be able to put up the final code you ended up with?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code posted above is that it doesn't handle subexpressions, which you seem to allow in the examples.  You seem to only allow binary `AND` and `OR`, and unary `NOT`, by design.  However, `and_operator` is not implemented, and subexpressions are not solved (by recursively calling `interpret()` and handling the value it returns).  Other functions such as `real_values` have no use.  Finally, the syntactic validity of input expressions and dictionaries has to be checked.

If you want to understand how interpreting works, you'd better follow some tutorial like [this](http://jayconrod.com/posts/37/a-simple-interpreter-from-scratch-in-python-part-1), [this](https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbasi-part1/), or [this](http://www.aosabook.org/en/500L/a-python-interpreter-written-in-python.html).  Otherwise, if you just need that function to work reliably, you may take advantage of existing, tested code, such as [parse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse), [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/), or even [parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html).