# How to parse AND/OR operator to evaluate a condition string in python

Tags: python, expression

If we have comparators `AND / OR` in a condition string such as

```
A != B AND C > 100
```

how do I parse this string and evaluate the result so that the following code returns false

```
A = "foo" B = "foo" C = 99  ->  eval("A != B AND C > 100") is false
```

I use the operator library to do the evaluation and do a naive check, but if we see AND then we need to finish the evaluation on both sides before using the AND operator. Is there a better way to do the parsing & evaluation?

```
import operator
ops = {
    "AND": operator.and_,
    "OR": operator.or_,
    "==": operator.eq,
    "!=": operator.ne,
    "<": operator.lt,
    "<=": operator.le,
    ">": operator.gt,
    ">=": operator.ge 
}
        result = false
        content = string.split(" ")
        for content in contents:
            if content in ops:
                    a = contents[i-1]
                    b = contents[i+1]
                result = ops[content](a, b)
                contents[i+1] = result
            i+=1
        if result is True:
            print("It is true")
```

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you're trying to evaluate this string without using eval()?

Comment: @Chris yes, I'm trying to manually parse the string and do the evaluation. I think one way to do it is to put "AND" and "OR" in a separate set and do the evaluation twice. In the first round we generate results from the basic comparators, then in the second round we check AND/OR and do the final evaluation on the previous results.

Comment: Parsing is a thing.  Maybe you want to use PLY?

Comment: recursion might help you like whenever you see `'AND'` make a recursive call with  `my_parser(string[i+1:]) `so that you can get the result of evaluation from right side. you can also implement short-circuit like if your string is `x AND y` if result of `x = 'False'` break,no need the interpret further and similarly for OR if string is `x or y` if x = True, break as your answer will always be `True` not matter what result comes from right side.

Comment: you may get some idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52584134/6360875) if you decide to use recursion

Comment: @Tanmayjain thanks. for now I'm just working with these operators and the "two pass" strategy works, but the recursion sounds better if we have more than two levels of priority between the operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not parsing the actual variables in this, but it should be able to do what you are asking for. It first evaluates the 0th priority, then evaluates the 1st, based on the 0th and so on. I have only tested it for a 2 priority, but I believe it should work for all. Heres how it functions.

```
['A', '!=', 'A', 'AND', 'B', '==', 'B']
[False, 'AND', True]
[False]
```

Heres the actual code:

```
import operator
ops = {
    "AND": operator.and_,
    "OR": operator.or_,
    "==": operator.eq,
    "!=": operator.ne,
    "<": operator.lt,
    "<=": operator.le,
    ">": operator.gt,
    ">=": operator.ge 
}
prior = {
    "AND": 1,
    "OR": 1,
    "==": 0,
    "!=": 0,
    "<": 0,
    "<=": 0,
    ">": 0,
    ">=": 0
}
maxPrior = 1
def parseEval(string):
    content = string.split()
    for priorMode in range(maxPrior+1):
        print(content)
        subParse = []
        subParse = []
        for ind,cont in enumerate(content):
            if cont in ops:
                priorLev = prior[cont]
                if priorLev <= priorMode:
                    condA = content[ind-1]
                    condB = content[ind+1]
                    subParse.append(ops[cont](condA,condB))
                else:
                    subParse.append(cont)   
        content = subParse
    print(content)
    return subParse[0]
parseEval("A != A OR B == B")
```

If you want you can make ops and prior inside the function. Also sorry, I should have given the ones meaning priority a better name, as it makes it sound like another word. Sorry if that gave confusion. If you have any questions please let me know, I'm happy to help!